# Hover effect on images (jquery/javascript)

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Im want a similar hover effect as the images on the front page of this website: http://www.arken.dk/default.aspx
I have made the html and css with hover effect but since the hover class only apply to one image at a time, the change in position will only be for one image at a time. 
As far as I can see, I will need some script to change the css of all the images whenever just one image is hovered. 
Also, it should not only be a hover effect. On the website the position of the images remains the same even after the image is no longer hovered?

Any one know how to do this or maybe have a link to a tutorial etc?

Im not sure what this effect is called so I havent been able to find anything useful on google :(

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: search for "horizontal accordion jquery". FYI, this kind of question doesn't really fit SO rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly do this using [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

Answer (score 1):

Working Example : http://jsfiddle.net/SBpzX/2/

```
<div id="container">  
    <div class="text">one</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text').hide();
    $('img').animate({
        opacity:1

    });

    $('img').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.4},200);
        $('.text').fadeIn();

    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},500)
        $('.text').fadeOut();
    });


});
```

**css**

```
img
{    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 267px;
}

.text {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sirushti, this was the solution i've been searching for.

Answer (score 0):

For instance one component from YUI library: http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/accordion-horiz-vert

Answer (score 0):

Download jquery and use it...

```
$(#'image need to be hovered').mouseover(function()
{
  $(#'images need be be cahnged in this effect').attr('src','image path')
})
```

For example: Give id for div as img1 and images need to be changed is img1,img2,img3

Consider this

```
$('#img1').mouseover(function()
    {
      $('#img1').attr('src','image path for hover image');
      $('#img2').attr('src','image path for hover image');
      $('#img3').attr('src','image path for hover image');
    });
```

and in mouseout

```
 $('#img1').mouseout(function()
        {
          $('#img1').attr('src','image path for original image');
          $('#img2').attr('src','image path for original image');
          $('#img3').attr('src','image path for original image');
        });
```